# SwiftUI Navigation Link not connecting views together on iPad correctly

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I've been working on this for a wee while but I seem to be having some issues. I'm trying to set up a basic navigation link on iPad using SwiftUI. However when I use the code below:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("HomePageiOS")
    VStack{
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: HomePageiOS()){
                    Text("Home")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: PublicDatabaseiOS()){
                    Text("Database")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: AddComponentFormiOS()){
                    Text("Add Component")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: MyInventoryPageiOS()){
                    Text("Inventory")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsPageiOS()){
                    Text("Settings")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: AboutPageiOS()){
                    Text("About")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }.navigationBarHidden(true)
    .navigationTitle("")
}
```

I get the following behaviour:

[Video of unexpected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJWb8.gif)

Alongside an error:

```
Unable to present. Please file a bug.
```

Has anyone experienced this before or know any workarounds?

I should probably also note all of this is happening inside another navigation link with the navigation bar hidden (since the user needs to be logged in and I'm using the link to change the views). If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit: So this appears to be an issue with SwiftUI itself, going to add a link to the forum here in case anyone finds this question:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677333

Also if anyone has any work arounds please feel free to add below.

Comment: Try to put `Text("HomePageiOS")`  inside `VStack`.

Comment: @Asperi I gave that a go, along with removing one of the VStacks (the outermost one), and it neither seem to have worked, still tinkering away, but any more suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var body: some View {
     NavigationView {
         VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: HomePageiOS()){
                    Text("Home")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: PublicDatabaseiOS()){
                    Text("Database")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: AddComponentFormiOS()){
                    Text("Add Component")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: MyInventoryPageiOS()){
                    Text("Inventory")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: SettingsPageiOS()){
                    Text("Settings")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                NavigationLink(destination: AboutPageiOS()){
                    Text("About")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("HomePageiOS")
        }
}
```

I´m not home and can't try it myself at this moment, but I think it should work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked unfortunately

Comment: Did you try to use the NavigationLink in a Form or List?